# How to create this dot graphic effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, reference-request

I am trying to recreate this dot graphic effect, but the method I was going to use, which was make a stack of lines, distort them using effects, and then create brush of dots with different spacing between them isn't working.

Here is the main graphic, and then highlighted focus areas of the intersection of the row of dots where you can see the different size and spacing of the dots that create the over all patten.

Image can be zoomed in on to see details.

All help in shining a light of understanding is Greatly appreciated! [image]

Comment: I think the entire design is screened, rather than each line being dots.

Comment: Dots are definitely too big to just be the screen. See my answer below.

Comment: It appears to be multiple screens that are a) warped to create curves then b) overlaid and rotated to create a moire effect. Illustrator is probably not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a halftone pattern. The easiest way to do something like this would be to edit your image to get solid lines, then use Illustrator/Photoshop's built-in halftone generator on a black/white image under Effect > pixelate > color halftone. Fiddling with the settings will allow you to fine tune the size and spread of the dots

Comment: I don't believe this is only a halftone pattern.  as the different directions of the rows of lines are visible on the sides of the graphic and even on the wear's left shoulder where there are rows of dots. Thanks, but I am looking for someone experienced in the steps it would take to create a graphic like.  Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: You seem to have ignored the first step in my explanation: Edit your image to create the lines, THEN apply the filter. This isn't just a case of adding a filter to a photo.

Comment: It could have been, at least *in effect*. It looks very much like the output of the [DGB Engraver](http://graphicriver.net/item/engrave-photoshop-actions-kit/1438626) Photoshop action set. (In any case, it uses the same techniques, the action + PSD is only $4, and dissecting it will get you where you want to go at a considerable time savings, even if you want to make a custom gravure pattern that matches the image contours exactly.)